# How to get Dictionary from Database by using Linq to entity?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I use something like this but some exception was occured. here is info about exception.

EXCEPTION:
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]] ToDictionary[<>f__AnonymousType5a`2,String,List`1](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType5a`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]]], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType5a`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]],System.String], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType5a`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

My code is here :

```
            List<Match> matches = new List<Match>();
        using (var en = new LiveOddsEntities())
        {
            matches = (from m in en.Matches
                       join mi in en.MatchInfoes on m.match_id equals mi.match_id
                       join to in en.Tournaments on mi.tournament_id equals to.id
                       join ca in en.Categories on mi.category_id equals ca.id
                       join sp in en.Sports on mi.sport_id equals sp.id
                       join ht in en.Teams on mi.home_team_id equals ht.id
                       join at in en.Teams on mi.away_team_id equals at.id
                       where mi.DateOfMatch > ticks
                       orderby mi.DateOfMatch ascending
                       select new Match { MatchId = m.match_id, DateOfMatch = mi.DateOfMatch, Tournament = to.name, Category = ca.name, Sport = sp.name, HomeTeam = ht.name, AwayTeam = at.name, BetTypes = (from mat in en.Matches
                                                                                                                                                                                                             join odd in en.Odds on mat.match_id equals odd.match_id
                                                                                                                                                                                                             select new { odd.type, proba = (from matc in en.Matches
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     join odds in en.Odds on matc.match_id equals odds.match_id
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     where odd.type ==odds.type
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     select odds.subtype).ToList()}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                ).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(k => k.type, k => k.proba) }).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        }
        return matches;
```

Comment: You can't use ToDictionary here. EF tries to convert your linq query to sql query so how it should convert ToDictionary? That's what exceptions is trying to tell you.

Comment: So I cna't do this in one query? I must do this in two separete queries first for match object and then with foreach to get this dictionary... am I right?

Comment: Yes. You need to use result of query and use it for your dictionary